# How do I check input variable validity from a Python extension?

Tags: python, c++

I have a Python extension written in C++ that expects a bytearray as the first parameter. It works correctly but if I pass something else from Python like a string or a number, I get a segmentation fault. How do I check if the input is *really* a bytearray and then raise an Exception if it's something else?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should help: http://docs.python.org/2/faq/extending.html#id8

> To test the type of an object, first make sure it isn’t `NULL`, and then use `PyString_Check()`, `PyTuple_Check()`, `PyList_Check()`, etc.

Specifically, it looks like you want this: http://docs.python.org/2/c-api/bytearray.html#type-check-macros

```
int PyByteArray_Check(PyObject *o)
```

> Return true if the object o is a bytearray object or an instance of a subtype of the bytearray type.

Comment: That worked. What is the check for NULL for? I tried passing None from Python but the object was still not NULL.

Comment: It's a recommendation, just in case your pointer happens to be NULL. They're saying that the `PyByteArray_Check` function doesn't do any null checking, so it will segfault if you pass it a null pointer.

Comment: What should I do if it happens to be NULL? Just raise an Exception or return NULL?

Comment: That depends on your program, but to me it sounds like based on your question that you expect a bytearray, and anything else would be exceptional, which merits raising an exception. You do that in CPython by calling one of the set error functions (such as `PyErr_SetString`) and returning NULL. http://docs.python.org/2/c-api/exceptions.html